# Putting Id name in string

Tags: android, string

***Got it to work but its longer than I wanted to be.***
 New Java:

```
package com.example.musicbynumbers;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class majorScales extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener  {
    Button aflatmaj, amaj, bflatmaj, bmaj, cmaj, dflatmaj, dmaj, eflatmaj, emaj, fmaj, fsharpmaj, gmaj;  
    ImageButton mainMenu;
    Intent j;
    String scaleName;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.majorscales);
        j  = new Intent(this, display.class);
        mainMenu = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagelogo);
        aflatmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aflatmajb);
        amaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.amajb);
        bflatmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bflatmajb);
        bmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bmajb);
        cmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmajb);
        dflatmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dflatmajb);
        dmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dmajb);
        eflatmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eflatmajb);
        emaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.emajb);
        fmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fmajb);
        fsharpmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fsharpmajb);
        gmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gmajb);
        mainMenu.setOnClickListener(this);
        aflatmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        amaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        bflatmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        bmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        cmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        dflatmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        dmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        eflatmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        emaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        fmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        fsharpmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        gmaj.setOnClickListener(this);



    }






         @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch(arg0.getId()){
                case R.id.imagelogo:
                    Intent i =  new Intent(majorScales.this, MainMenu.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
                case R.id.aflatmajb:
                    scaleName = "aflatmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);

                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.amajb:
                    scaleName = "aflatmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.bflatmajb:
                    scaleName = "aflatmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.bmajb:
                    scaleName = "aflatmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.cmajb:
                    scaleName = "aflatmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.dflatmajb:
                    scaleName = "aflatmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.dmajb:
                    scaleName = "aflatmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.eflatmajb:
                    scaleName = "aflatmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.emajb:
                    scaleName = "aflatmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.fmajb:
                    scaleName = "aflatmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.fsharpmajb:
                    scaleName = "aflatmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.gmajb:
                    scaleName = "aflatmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;




    }

}
}



package com.example.musicbynumbers;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class display extends Activity {
    ImageView displayScale;
    ImageButton logoButton;
    String gotScale;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display);
        Initalize();
        gotScale = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
        ImageView displayScale = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.displayImage);
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier("com.example.musicbynumbers:drawable/" + gotScale, null, null);
        displayScale.setImageResource(id);
    }

    private void Initalize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        displayScale = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.displayImage);
        logoButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagelogo);
        gotScale = "ic_launcher.png";

    }

}
```

---

I'm trying to get the id name and put it in a string and then for it to go to another activity and open a resource picture with the corresponding filename

eg.

r.id.x
 get x and put it in string y
then send it to a different activity 
how do i get x and put it in the string?

I know there's an easy answer to this because I'm very new to programming.

```
package com.example.musicbynumbers;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class majorScales extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener  {
    Button aflatmaj, amaj, bflatmaj, bmaj, cmaj, dflatmaj, dmaj, eflatmaj, emaj, fmaj, fsharpmaj, gmaj;  
    ImageButton mainMenu;
    Intent j;
    String scaleName;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.majorscales);
        j  = new Intent(this, display.class);
        mainMenu = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagelogo);
        aflatmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aflatmajb);
        amaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.amajb);
        bflatmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bflatmajb);
        bmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bmajb);
        cmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmajb);
        dflatmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dflatmajb);
        dmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dmajb);
        eflatmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eflatmajb);
        emaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.emajb);
        fmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fmajb);
        fsharpmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fsharpmajb);
        gmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gmajb);
        mainMenu.setOnClickListener(this);
        aflatmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        amaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        bflatmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        bmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        cmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        dflatmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        dmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        eflatmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        emaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        fmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        fsharpmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        gmaj.setOnClickListener(this);



    }




         @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch(arg0.getId()){
                case R.id.imagelogo:
                    Intent i =  new Intent(majorScales.this, MainMenu.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
                case R.id.aflatmajb:
                    scaleName = 

                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.amajb:

                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.bflatmajb:

                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.bmajb:

                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.cmajb:

                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.dflatmajb:

                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.dmajb:
                    ;
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.eflatmajb:
                    ;
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.emajb:
                    ;
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.fmajb:
                    ;
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.fsharpmajb:
                    ;
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.gmajb:
                    ;
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;



    }

}
}
```

For example in the switch case for "R.id.aflatmajb" I want the part after the r.id. (aflatmajb) to be put in a string  is there a way to do that or will I have to do it manually for every button in every menu?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean passing data between activities as you transition?
You'd do

```
// This is a String, you can use a lot of data types
String theData = "This is some data I need to send along";

// Create a new Intent that will start NextActivity
Intent i = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);

// Add the data to the Intent using any key you want (which is how you reference the data)
i.putExtra("key", theData);

// Start the activity
startActivity(i);
```

Then you'd get the data from the `Intent` in the second activity:

```
// getIntent() returns the Intent that was used to start the current Activity
String theData = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```

Comment: I can do that what i need is how to get the text from each of the ids of the buttons and put them in a string because there's more than a hundred buttons on different menus I have to do

Comment: `((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_id)).getId();` ?

EDIT: When a button is pressed, provider you added a listener, `onClick(View v)` is fired on the listener. You can do `v.getViewId()` to get the id of the button that was pressed.

EDIT 2: Sorry, `getId()`. `getViewId()` is for `ListView`s.

Comment: If I don't have too many `Button`s, I often call `setOnClickListener(this)` on all of them, and let the `Activity` implement `OnClickListener`. In the event handler method, I then do a `switch(v.getId()) {}` to determine which button was pressed and what action I have to undertake. You may want to consider alternative ways if you have a lot of (you mentioned 100+) buttons

Comment: @RobinKanters : Perhaps the OP will find a way to get it to work with your suggestion but the original question is to get *text*. Resource ids are `int` values and that's what `getId()` returns.

Comment: I'll update with the java. This was just to save time I can do it the long way if there is no way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

***Got it to work but its longer than I wanted to be.***
 New Java:

```
package com.example.musicbynumbers;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class majorScales extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener  {
    Button aflatmaj, amaj, bflatmaj, bmaj, cmaj, dflatmaj, dmaj, eflatmaj, emaj, fmaj, fsharpmaj, gmaj;  
    ImageButton mainMenu;
    Intent j;
    String scaleName;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.majorscales);
        j  = new Intent(this, display.class);
        mainMenu = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagelogo);
        aflatmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aflatmajb);
        amaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.amajb);
        bflatmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bflatmajb);
        bmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bmajb);
        cmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmajb);
        dflatmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dflatmajb);
        dmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dmajb);
        eflatmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eflatmajb);
        emaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.emajb);
        fmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fmajb);
        fsharpmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fsharpmajb);
        gmaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gmajb);
        mainMenu.setOnClickListener(this);
        aflatmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        amaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        bflatmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        bmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        cmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        dflatmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        dmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        eflatmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        emaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        fmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        fsharpmaj.setOnClickListener(this);
        gmaj.setOnClickListener(this);



    }






         @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch(arg0.getId()){
                case R.id.imagelogo:
                    Intent i =  new Intent(majorScales.this, MainMenu.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
                case R.id.aflatmajb:
                    scaleName = "aflatmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);

                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.amajb:
                    scaleName = "aflatmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.bflatmajb:
                    scaleName = "aflatmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.bmajb:
                    scaleName = "aflatmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.cmajb:
                    scaleName = "aflatmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.dflatmajb:
                    scaleName = "aflatmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.dmajb:
                    scaleName = "aflatmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.eflatmajb:
                    scaleName = "aflatmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.emajb:
                    scaleName = "aflatmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.fmajb:
                    scaleName = "aflatmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.fsharpmajb:
                    scaleName = "aflatmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.gmajb:
                    scaleName = "aflatmaj";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;




    }

}
}



package com.example.musicbynumbers;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class display extends Activity {
    ImageView displayScale;
    ImageButton logoButton;
    String gotScale;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display);
        Initalize();
        gotScale = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
        ImageView displayScale = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.displayImage);
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier("com.example.musicbynumbers:drawable/" + gotScale, null, null);
        displayScale.setImageResource(id);
    }

    private void Initalize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        displayScale = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.displayImage);
        logoButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagelogo);
        gotScale = "ic_launcher.png";

    }

}
```